# Using Twitters API

Tags: python, api, twitter

When I try hitting their API I get hit with an error for Authentication. I'm not using this for an application, but just writing a few scripts to play around.

```
r = requests.get('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json?screen_name=dhh')
print r.text
```

Returns

```
{"errors":[{"message":"Bad Authentication data","code":215}]}
```

Can someone explain how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look here https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth
You must be authenticated at first to make such request per requirements here https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/users/show

You can use this library http://code.google.com/p/python-twitter/ for your requests

Comment: I saw the documentation, but I wasn't really sure how to write the code to provide the auth key?

Comment: then just use the library above, it's the easiest way